# Textarea (asp:Textbox TextMode="Multiline") overlapping buttons

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, multiline

I'm having this problem with form buttons overlapping an asp:Texbox with TextMode set to multi-line:
[alt text http://www.nango.co.uk/forums/uploads/1251792203/gallery_2_3_18518.jpg](http://www.nango.co.uk/forums/uploads/1251792203/gallery_2_3_18518.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGiftStep" Visible="false" runat="server">
                <img src="/images/shopping-cart/form-separator.png" alt="separator" />
                <div class="form-title">GIFT OPTIONS</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGiftName" Height="31" Width="323" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Arial"
                        Font-Size="116.7%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="wmeGiftName"
                        TargetControlID="txtGiftName" WatermarkText="Gift Name"
                        WatermarkCssClass="watermark" runat="server"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGiftMessage" Rows="5" Width="323" BorderStyle="None" 
                        Font-Names="Arial" TextMode="MultiLine"
                        Font-Size="116.7%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="wmeGiftMessage"
                        TargetControlID="txtGiftMessage" WatermarkText="Gift Message"
                        WatermarkCssClass="watermark" runat="server"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
                <div class="button-row">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imbShippingDetails" 
                        ImageUrl="/images/shopping-cart/ship-details-btn.png"
                        OnClick="ReturnToShipping"
                        ValidationGroup="shipping"
                        runat="server" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imbPayDetails" ImageUrl="/images/shopping-cart/pay-details-btn.png"
                        ValidationGroup="pay"
                        runat="server" />
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
            </asp:Panel>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.row
{
    float:left;
    height:40px;
}

.button-row
{
    float:left;
    width:323px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Any ideas how I can stop this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your URL i can surely help you with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's laying out exactly as you told it to. The class you assign `.row` has a height property of 40px. Since you specified the height the container div is only 40 px high which is why your buttons appear on top of it. If you added a `style="overflow: hidden"` to the div holding the textarea you'd notice that most of that textarea disappeared. You'll either need to add a new style that overrides the height property or remove the class all together from that div.

When working with these kinds of layout issues it can be helpful to add a `border` or `background-color` property to the classes you're suspecting to help you visualize what's going on. In this case your multiline textbox is overflowing outside of the 40px div.

Comment: I know how that goes. Nothing is worse than screaming at it "why won't you work?" and finding out that it was, and not only that but it did *exactly* what you told it to. I've had plenty of cases of "do what I _want_ not what I _say_!" :)